# Finding the sum and adding a probability scale

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working on an assignment where I need to create a fully functioning Yahtzee program. I am now done with the initial task, and have a fully functioning Yahtzee application, so I can roll the dice and I can hold values etc.
But the problem I am facing right now is that I need to add 2 special dies to the mix, one of the dies need to have a higher probability of outputting low numbers while the other die need to have a higher probability of outputting higher numbers, also I need to provide a way for the user to adjust the probability on these dies within the console window.

So basically I was looking around on the internet and it seemed like, if I hardcoded it with an array, where I basically put more low numbers than high numbers, it does work, but that is very messy, and also doesn't fix the issue and also makes the task of allowing the user to adjust the probability very silly.

Long time since I've used the site, apologize if this is a bit sloppy.

```
class Dice
{
    public static readonly Random rng = new Random();

        public int NumberOfDice { get; private set; }

        public Dice()
        {
            NumberOfDice = rng.Next(1, 7);
        }

        public void Reroll()
        {
            NumberOfDice = rng.Next(1, 7);
        }
    }

    public bool FirstRound { get; private set; } = true;

    public readonly Dice[] Dices =
    {
        new Dice(),
        new Dice(),
        new Dice(),
        new Dice(),
        new Dice(),

    public void KeepDices(int[] toReroll)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Dices.Length; i++)
        {
            bool numFound = false;

            foreach (int roll in toReroll)
            {
                if (Dices[i].NumberOfDice == roll)
                {
                    numFound = true;
                }
            }

            if (numFound)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                Dices[i].Reroll();
            }
        }

        ShowDices();
    }

    public void ShowDices()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (Dice dice in Dices)
        {
            Console.Write("[{0}] ", dice.NumberOfDice);
            FirstRound = false;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void RerollAll()
    {
        foreach (Dice dice in Dices)
        {
            dice.Reroll();
        }

        ShowDices();
    }
}
```

As I said the program runs fine, it works, but just need to somehow add a way to tie two of the dices to probability.

Comment: "one of the dices need to have a higher probability of outputting low numbers while the other dice need to have a higher probability of outputting higher numbers" Can you define that more formally? Do you mean one dice has a probability of x of rolling 4, 5 or 6, while the other one has a probability of y of rolling a 1, 2, or 3, where x and y are both greater than 0.5?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response, basically I need 1 die to have a higher chance of rolling 1, 2 ,3 and therefore also a lower chance of rolling 4,5,6
And then the other die to have a higher chance of rolling 4,5,6 and lower chance of rolling 1,2,3

And then for some way to allow the user to adjust the likelyhood of rolling either low or high numbers, thats at least how I understand the assignment.

And yeah, basically what you wrote is correct I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently written a 40-part blog series on how to more elegantly build randomness into C# programs. Your problem is covered in part 9:

https://ericlippert.com/2019/02/28/fixing-random-part-9/

In short: create a *non uniform weighted distribution object* to represent the distribution. You can implement it efficiently with the *alias method*. You then *sample* from that distribution to roll your die.

You can then create a game distribution by summing the results of various die distributions, and sample from it.

I suggest that you read the entire series; you will learn a lot from it. It begins here:

https://ericlippert.com/2019/01/31/fixing-random-part-1/

You can find the source code for the implementation of the alias method here:

https://github.com/ericlippert/probability/tree/episode09

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of probabilities for each face of the dice.

```
var loadedDice = new double[] { 0.1, 0.12, 0.18, 0.2, 0.21, 0.19 };
```

Now you generate a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 and calculate a running sum of these probabilities, until the sum is greater or equal to the random number.

```
// Play the dice
double p = rng.NextDouble() * loadedDice.Sum();

double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    sum += loadedDice[i];
    if (sum >= p) {
        Console.Write($"The number is {i + 1}");
        break;
    }
}
```

We add one, because the indexes start at 0.

---

Example:

The `x`s in this image represent the running sum. The distances between them correspond to the probabilities  in the array. If say we get a random number of 0.27239827 (`p` in the image), then the running sum becomes greater than `p` for index = 2. We rolled number 3.

```
     x     x p      x         x          x        x
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
0   0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9  1.0
```

Comment: Though this technique can work, there are a few problems with it. First, since you're using doubles, there are some rare cases where doubles that you think add up to 1.0 do not, and that can then lead in very rare cases to a value not being picked from the list. I'm sure you can see how to tweak the implementation so that if you get to round 6, you automatically produce the right result. Alternatively, do the math in integers: 1000, 1200, 1800, and so on, and then generate a random integer from 0 to the sum.

Comment: Second, on average this does three or four loops per roll, which is almost certainly just fine. But it is interesting to think about what happens if you have a 100-sided or 1000-sided die; then you end up doing on average possibly hundreds of loops per roll. To solve this problem you can do some precomputation to build a distribution that samples *two* random numbers and does only one comparison, no matter how many sides the die has. See part 8 of my recent series on "fixing random" for a description of the algorithm.

Comment: For the case where the doubles do not add up to 1.0 I proposed the line `double p = rng.NextDouble() * loadedDice.Sum();`. This should also produce the same rounding errors as in the running sum calculation. If it is still a problem just add a constant to the last probability (after having calculated the sum for the `p` calculation). The algorithm you described in [Fixing Random, part 8](https://ericlippert.com/2019/02/26/fixing-random-part-8/) is very interesting indeed. It could easily be adapted to doubles and would not have this rounding problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a property called `ChanceOfRollingSmallNumber` into your `Dice` class:

```
public int ChanceOfRollingSmallNumber { get; set; } = 50;
```

When rolling the dice, generate a random number between 0 and 99. If the number is less than the `ChanceOfRollingSmallNumber`, then generate a small random number, otherwise generate a large random number:

```
if (rng.Next(100) < ChanceOfRollingSmallNumber) {
    NumberOfDice = rng.Next(1, 4);
} else {
    NumberOfDice = rng.Next(4, 7);
}
```

For the dice that has a high probability of rolling a small number, just set `ChanceOfRollingSmallNumber` to something big. For the dice that has a high probably of rolling a big number, just set it to something small. For the fair dices, just set it to 50.

If you want even finer tuning, you could make `ChanceOfRollingSmallNumber` range from 0 to 1000, or something even bigger than that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a weighted random number generator.

So I think you should be able to adopt this solution for your need.

First, a weight class to define your weights. This would be what you'd use for your sides of the dice.

```
public class WeightUnit
{
    public string Name = string.Empty;
    public int Weight = 0;

    public WeightUnit(string n, int w)
    {
        this.Name = n;
        this.Weight = w;
    }
}
```

Then this method will return a weighted random number:

```
public static WeightUnit GetRandom(List<WeightUnit> weights)
{
    var totalWeight = weights.Sum(x => x.Weight);
    int randomNumber = _rnd.Next(0, totalWeight);

    WeightUnit selected = null;
    foreach (WeightUnit unit in weights)
    {
        if (randomNumber < unit.Weight)
        {
            selected = unit;
            break;
        }

        randomNumber = randomNumber - unit.Weight;
    }

    return selected;
}
```

And here's a main program to verify:

```
private static Random _rnd = new Random();

static void Main()
{
    List<WeightUnit> weights = new List<WeightUnit>
    {
        new WeightUnit("1", 20),
        new WeightUnit("2", 20),
        new WeightUnit("3", 20),
        new WeightUnit("4", 10),
        new WeightUnit("5", 10),
        new WeightUnit("6", 10)
    };

    Dictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    WeightUnit selected = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        selected = GetRandom(weights);
        if (selected != null)
        {
            if (result.ContainsKey(selected.Name))
            {
                result[selected.Name] = result[selected.Name] + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(selected.Name, 1);
            }
        }
    }


    Console.WriteLine("1\t\t" + result["1"]);
    Console.WriteLine("2\t\t" + result["2"]);
    Console.WriteLine("3\t\t" + result["3"]);
    Console.WriteLine("4\t\t" + result["4"]);
    Console.WriteLine("5\t\t" + result["5"]);
    Console.WriteLine("6\t\t" + result["6"]);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As you can see, I've assigned twice the weightage for numbers 1,2, and 3, and over 1,000 iterations they're selected twice as many times compared to 4, 5, and 5. So when you're making your list you can assign the weightage you want.

[image]